# css - Navigation bug

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have troubles creating a navigation bar for my website.

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="headertext"><a class="headerlink" href="index">sample text</a></div>
    <div class="headernav"><a class="headerlink" href="index">HOME</a></div>
    <div class="headernav"><a class="headerlink" href="index">ABOUT</a></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    background: #2980b9;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #3498db;
    color: white;
}

#header .headerlink {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

#header .headertext {
   display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    line-height: 80px;
}

#header .headernav {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    right: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    line-height: 80px;
}
```

The left side seems ok, but i have problems on the right side ...
http://jsfiddle.net/024pvmxp/

How can i fix this?

Comment: you should review your css. presently its working as intended. consider using float(s)

Comment: Try using an unordered list instead of divs for the nav text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is:

```
#header .headernav {
    position: absolute;
}
```

With absolute positioning all your `.headernav` elements will be place in exactly the the same 'absolute' position. You probably want to use `position: relative`. See http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/ as a guide.

Answer (score 0):

There you go [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmyamsva/) :) And yeah your problem was absolute position (it takes your element's out of normal flow so they are on top of each other). In some cases it is desired behavior but not in your case...

```
#header {
background: #2980b9;
height: 80px;
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 3px solid #3498db;
color: white;
}

#header .headerlink {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}

#header .headertext {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
float:left;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: lighter;
line-height: 80px;
margin-left:15px;
}

#header .headernav {
position: relative;
display: block;
text-align: right;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: lighter;
line-height: 80px;
float:right;
margin-right:15px;
}
```